# Delete Empty columns in Ms Excel 2010

Tags: excel, csv, multiple-columns

I have a CSV file in which I have lots of empty columns. I have Ms Excel 2010 but, I don't know how to use Macros or sort functions.

I already did a Google search and followed the steps. They didn't help me. Can someone guide me through step by step process for deleting empty columns?

**Edited:**

Sorry, I didn't know how this site works. It was hard for me to go through my web search history to find out the proper links as I have been searching all day.

But I have some links from my history that were helpful for similar people like me (but not me :()

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-delete-remove-blank-rows-columns-in-excel-2010-spreadsheet/
http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/11225.html

Comment: Can you provide the link to the page you used and/or the steps you used? Also, can you provide an example column (just a CSV line). Are these columns entirely-empty?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how this site works. It's hard for me to go through my web search history to find out the proper links as I have been searching all day. 

But wait, I did find some links from my history that were helpful for similar people like me (but not me :()

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-delete-remove-blank-rows-columns-in-excel-2010-spreadsheet/
http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/11225.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a macro that will go through all columns, from the last one with any data in it to the first, and delete any columns that have nothing in them:

```
Sub DeleteEmptyColumns()

    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not r Is Nothing Then

        lastColumn = r.Column

        For i = lastColumn To 1 Step -1

            Set r = ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

            If r Is Nothing Then
                ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Delete
            Else
                If r.Row = 1 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Delete
                End If
            End If

        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

In addition: it won't crash if there's nothing at all in the sheet, and you don't have to limit yourself to a certain number of columns, it'll check all of them automatically.

**EDIT:** Modified to skip the first row and ignore any headers.

Comment: This one was very close to my requirement. But, I'm not done yet. I have headers which I had to remove to make this macro work. But, now I am missing the map of headers vs data. Can you help? I see the number of columns reduced from CJ to Y (which is 25 from 88) thx

Comment: @RubenKf Yes, if there are headers then the columns will not be removed since there is data in them. So I'm not sure what you want: do you want a column removed if there is a header but no text beneath it?

Comment: hi Sid. yes. I want to "skip the first row from validation" to be exact.

Comment: @RubenKf OK, I've modified it so that it'll skip the headers. Give it another go and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @RubenKf can you edit your question to include the headers and the first couple of rows? That might be very helpful!

Comment: @SidHolland: Thx. That worked. Sorry for dragging.

Comment: @Thumper: thx for attempting to help. It's resolved now. I'm happy.

Comment: @RubenKf No problem. You should tick whichever answer you went with so that people know in future which one to use (and an upvote for the other wouldn't hurt ;)

Comment: @SidHolland : Vote up requires at least 15 reputation. I will surely increase my reputation and vote this up.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have something like:

```
1,,,,4,55,,92,,,,,,,,,62,
3,,,,7,43,,12,,,,,,,,,74,
7,,,,3,58,,52,,,,,,,,,64,
0,,,,6,10,,22,,,,,,,,,96,
3,,,,8,13,,92,,,,,,,,,22,
```

For your CSV file, what you want to do is the following in Excel 2010:
1. Save a copy of your file (just in case you get something wrong here)
2. Press Alt+F11
3. Double-Click on Sheet1(Book1) - or whatever you sheet name is. (It's under Microsoft Excel Objects.
4. Copy and paste this code into the window called Book1.csv - Sheet1 (Code)

```
Sub showMessage()
    Dim cChar As String
    Dim Index As Integer
    For Index = 0 To 25
        cChar = Chr(90-Index)
        if Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(cChar)) = 0 Then
            Columns(cChar).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next Index
End Sub
```

5. Click on the green arrow in the tools at the top. (Alternatively, press F5)
Note, the values you may have to modify are "25" and "90". These have to do with converting from ASCII to characters. You can play around with that, if you like.

What this does is Looks at columns Z through A (yes, in reverse) and deletes any that do not have data in them.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, it didn't work very well. Maybe I'm missing something obvious. I did hit run and the screen was just calm; no response. 

The CSV I have is exported from Google contacts. So, you know the number of columns is up to CJ. There are at least 40-50 empty columns.

What I'm trying to do here is to export my Google contacts, remove unwanted contacts (out of 3k+) and make my Android phone display only contacts that I want. There are duplicates too. I found it difficult to merge contacts in android phone. So, I thought of approaching this way.